# Landau's constant, the norms of partial sum operators on $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

I learn from some papers ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870813004696?via%3Dihub)) that E. Landau proved the following theorem in his 1913 paper: *E. Landau
Abschätzung der Koeffzientensumme einer Potenzreihe, Arch. Math. Phys., 21 (42–50) (1913), pp. 250-255.*

Denote by $H^\infty$ the Banach space consisting of all bounded analytic functions on the unit disc $\mathbb D$. The norm is naturally defined by $$\|f\|=\sup_{z\in \mathbb D} |f(z)|.$$ For an integer $n\geq 0$, let $S_n$ denote the n-th partial sum operator $$S_n f= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k, \quad {\rm if}\,\,\,\,\, f=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k.$$

> Theorem: The operator norm of $S_n$ is given by $$\|S_n\|=\sum_{k=0}^n \big(\frac{1}{4^k} C_{2k}^k \big)^2. $$

I was interested in this result and try to find a proof of this theorem. Unfortunately, although Landau's original paper was widely cited, it is not available in MathReview and Google Scholar. I will be very grateful if someone could help me to find the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fairly straightforward using that by Cauchy $s_n(f)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_n$ satisfies $$2\pi i s_n=\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)(1+z+..+z^n)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

But using one more time Cauchy we notice that the integral above is also $\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)P(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$ where $P$ is any polynomial of the form $1+z+..z^n+z^{n+1}R(z)$ with arbitrary polynomial $R$

Now if $K_n(z)= 1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1 \times 3...\times 2k-1}{2 \times 4... \times 2k}z^k$ Enestrom-Kakeya theorem shows that it has no zeroes in the closed unit disc (coefficients satisfy $c_0>c_1..>c_n>0$)

If $K(z)$ is the infinite series above ($\lim_{n \to \infty} K_n$) we have the well known identity (generalized binomial theorem) $K^2(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum z^k$ so we get that $K_n^2(z)=1+z+..z^n+z^{n+1}R_n(z)$ for some polynomial $R_n$ so we can use $K_n^2$ in the integral for $s_n$ above

Since we can compute the norm $||S_n||$ as the maximum of $|s_n(f)|$ when $|f(z)| \le 1$ in the unit disc, we immediately get by the triangle inequality that $2\pi ||S_n|| \le \frac{1}{r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}|K_n(re^{it})|^2dt$

Letting $r\to 1$ gives that $$||S_n||\le 1+\sum_{k=1}^n(\frac{1\times 3...\times 2k-1}{2\times 4..\times 2k})^2=G_n$$ as required.

For equality consider $f(z)=\frac{z^nK_n(1/z)}{K_n(z)}$ which is analytic in the closed unit disc as we proved above that $K_n$ has no zeroes there. Since $K_n$ has real coefficients it immediately follows that $|f(e^{it})|=1$ since $K_n(e^{-it})=\overline {K_n(e^{it})}$ and using this $f$ in the integral for $s_n(f)$ above for $r=1$ which is allowed as $f$ is analytic on the closed unit circle, it is immediate that we get $2\pi s_n(f)=\int_0^{2\pi}|K_n(e^{it})|^2dt$ hence $s_n(f)=G_n$ and so $||S_n||=G_n$ as required!

Comment: Perfect answer! I would like to remark that $$\frac{1}{4^k}C_{2k}^k=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}=\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(k+1)},$$ and $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(k+1)}z^k.$$

Comment: Happy to be of help - while $\frac{1}{4^k} {2k \choose k}$ is useful for asymptotics, I like the $\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}=\frac{1 \times 3...\times 2k-1}{2 \times 4... \times 2k}$ notation as it (more or less) clearly shows that is a binomial coefficient which appears in various interesting places